# Is there an equivalent of parent_activity for fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

For example, with parent activity we can have something like this

[image]

Is there an equivalent for fragments? I'd like to have something like
[image]

Comment: you mean a toolbar in the fragment. aren't you?

Comment: sort of, but i ended up using a workaround with onclick listeners